# .post adding new value

Tags: jquery

I have found some script on internet "voting system", I want to modify it a little, so I have this piece of code:

```
$.post(
    "voting/voting.php?value="+a, 
    { }, 
    function(response) {
        // now update box bar           
        $.post(
            "voting/update_box.php", 
            { }, 
            function(update){
                $('#update_count').html(unescape(update));              
            }
        );
        ////////////

        // now update tooltip count         
        $.post(
            "voting/update_tooltip.php", 
            { }, 
            function(updates){
                $('.tooltip3').html(unescape(updates));             
            }
        );
        ////////////
    }
);
```

You see in the first line `voting/voting.php?value="+a`, I want to add another value there - `video`, where will be stored `id` of current video, and to pass it to `voting.php` together with `value`.

I tried this (I am storing video `id` as id of div with `.tooltip` class, I know it is litle strange, but i think it should work):

```
var b = $(".tooltip").attr("id");
$.post("voting/voting.php?video="+b+"&value="+a, {
```

but this doesnt work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$.post("voting/voting.php", {"value":a,"video":b },
function(response)...
```

This will send the parameters in `POST` method.